# How to create this variable?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to create a variable similar to a dictionary like that:

```
parameters['Cell']['volume'] = 5    
parameters['Project']['winterTemp'] = 30
```

I have tried to do:

```
parameters = dict()    
parameters['volume'] = 5
```

It works, but how can I create a "two dimensional" dictionary like the example where I could store the cell number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make a dictionary as value for 'Cell' then assign a key, value of 'volume':5 to it.  the answer would be like this:

```
parameters = {'Cell' : {'volume' : 5}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I was looking for

Comment: @SergioManchado you're very welcome :) .  Please accept the answers that are helpful by clicking the check mark :) .

Answer (score 2):

The same way you defined `parameters` to be a dictionary, you can define any key in `parameters` to be a dictionary too, like this:

```
parameters = dict()
parameters['Cell'] = dict()   # same as parameters['Cell'] = {}
```

Or like this:

```
parameters = {'Cell': {}}
```

You can also use the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) package to define the default value in `parameters` to be a dictionary like this:

```
parameters = collections.defaultdict(dict)
print parameters['Cell']
>> {}
```